# saveAs работает только 1 раз

Tags: javascript

Нужна функция для сохранения данных в файл, решил использовать библиотеку https://cdn.rawgit.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/master/FileSaver.js

На всех сайтах работает хорошо, но при попытке сохранить текст ВК - первый раз все проходит успешно, после чего функция будто умирает и полностью перестает работать до переоткрытия вкладки (закрытие, а потом открытие).

В чем может быть проблема?

Вот код, попробуйте сами:

```
function includeJS(src){
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';

    script.src = src;
    head.appendChild(script);
}
includeJS('https://cdn.rawgit.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/master/FileSaver.js');
```

А вот создание файла

```
var blob = new Blob(['Тестовое сообщение'], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(blob, 'filename.txt')
```

Comment: Ого, а что, для такой простой операции в JS уже нужна библиотека?

Comment: А ты знаешь способ иначе сохранять файл? Кроме как через временное создание ссылки на data: ? Если да, рассказывай.

Comment: Я плохо знаю  JS, но достаточно неплохо знаю несколько других языков. Везде запись данных в файл — базовая функция языка, не требующая сторонних библиотек.

Comment: В JS есть свои ограничения из соображений о безопасности и приватности. Например нельзя распознать посещенные ссылки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Проблема" была в запрете для этого сайта автоматической загрузки